# How to pass default value to ajax while retrieving data from mysql in php

Tags: php, ajax, http

I need to get different fields from mysql database table in php using ajax.
I did that using the following code. But I need to get some default value when I load the page without clicking any select button.

My code is

Ajax Code

```
<script>
    function langchange()
    {

        var langs= $('#langs').val();

       $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajax_lang_change.php",
        data:"id="+langs,
        success:function(value){
            var data=value.split("|_,_|";
             for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            $("#cat_desc"+i).html(data[i]);
        }
    }
            });       
    }

    </script>
```

Php/html script

```
<select name="sources" id="langs"  onchange="langchange();"  placeholder="English">
                                            <?php
                                            $language=mysqli_query($link,"select * from language_reference";
                                            while($lang=mysqli_fetch_array($language))
                                            {
                                            ?>
                                             <option value="<?php echo $lang['lang_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $lang['lang_name']; ?>

                                             </option>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                          </select>
```

Any help?? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, then you can call the langchange() on page load and it will take currently selected option from the langs select element

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    langchange();
});
```

Comment: How to load selected language on page reload?? or how to load it in session?

Comment: In your mysql loop "while($lang=mysqli_fetch_array($language)){" add $selected = ''; if(isset($_SESSION['session_lang_key']) && $_SESSION['session_lang_key']==$lang['lang_id']) $selected = 'selected="selected"''; and then in option line add <?php echo $selected; ?> instead of selected="selected"